# Origin of LITE(tm) book summaries in fortune

Tags: debian, shell, terminal

Debian `fortunes-min` package provide `/usr/share/games/fortunes/literature` file. Among other epigrams it contains ultra short book summaries marked with **LITE(tm)**.

What is the origin of this? Where the entire list can be found?

Google Search suggests a number of pages, most of which with a copy of this specific cookie or of entire file. The only links resembling a real origin I found is https://joederbes.wordpress.com/2005/05/04/great-books-litetm/ and https://joederbes.wordpress.com/2005/11/25/more-great-books-litetm/.

Here is the complete text:

```
A Tale of Two Cities LITE(tm)
    -- by Charles Dickens

    A lawyer who looks like a French Nobleman is executed in his place.

The Metamorphosis LITE(tm)
    -- by Franz Kafka

    A man turns into a bug and his family gets annoyed.

Lord of the Rings LITE(tm)
    -- by J. R. R. Tolkien

    Some guys take a long vacation to throw a ring into a volcano.

Hamlet LITE(tm)
    -- by Wm. Shakespeare

    A college student on vacation with family problems, a screwy
    girl-friend and a mother who won't act her age.
```

Comment: For those interested in using the literature type on fortune `fortune -e literature`.

Comment: Maybe you should contact the guy who wrote the blog.